# Backbone extend function error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following collection model

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/domain'
], function(_, Backbone, DomainModel){
  var DomainCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : DomainModel,
    getAll : function() {
      console.log('test');
    }.
  });   // <--- error here
  return DomainCollection;
});
```

It throws an err or on the line specified above:

> SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '}' instead

If I remove the `getAll` function, it works. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Comment: Is the `.` after `getAll : function() {console.log('test');}` a typo?

Comment: yes sorry, fixed. EDIT: I take that back, that WAS the problem. I have been at this for too long today...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getAll : function() {
  console.log('test');
}. // <---- error here
```

Should be more like:

```
var DomainCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : DomainModel,
  getAll : function() {
    console.log('test');
  } // no period
});
```

Comment: Yep you got that right, I have been coding for too long today and mistook the full stop for a comma.

Comment: @Rikkles happens to us all. Feel free to delete the question if you want to. It may not really help future visitors. Your call.

Comment: can't do that, it's got answers, don't worry about it. thanks.